# ListView displays item after 2nd item has been created

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity

So I'm having a weird order of events in my code. It'll probably be something minor that I haven't seen yet. A have `ListView` that and is pulling the string from an `EditText` after button click.

The `EditText` lives in a dialog that's being pulled back to the main `Activity` by an `interface`

What happens now, is when I type something in the `EditText` field say "a", nothing shows up. But when I go to add another, "b", "a" shows up. and so forth. So one has to be created in order for the previous to show up.

Here's my what I have.

```
public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AddSiteDialog.AddSiteDialogListener {

ListView mSiteListView;
ArrayList<String> siteList = new ArrayList<String>();
CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_site);
    mSiteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.siteAddList);
    arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    mSiteListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           showDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void showDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    AddSiteDialog addSiteDialog = new AddSiteDialog();
    addSiteDialog.show(fm, "main");
}

public void onSignIn(String inputText) {
    siteList.add(inputText);

}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    CustomAdapter() {
        super(NewActivity.this, R.layout.add_site, siteList);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewId)).setText(siteList.get(position));

        return (row);
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone spot where this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

## Simple.

call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in

```
public void onSignIn(String inputText) {
    siteList.add(inputText);
    //add that here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data which is backed by your adapter changes, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to instruct the `ListView` to update itself.

I don't see anything like that in your code.

Just to add:

Your adapter implementation is sub-optimal - although in this case it doesn't really matter.
You should create a ViewHolder and store it as your View's tag, so that you can retrieve it if convertView is given. The ViewHolder should keep references to all sub-views of your view (`TextView`, `ImageView`, whatever you need to update). This would avoid the repeated call to `findViewById()` - which is slow.

Comment: Just watched that google IO video an hour or so ago ... I totally understand what you're saying :)